# Horizontal scrolling on a DIV that contains a UL that "grows"

Tags: css, knockout.js, html-lists

```
here's a fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattlokk/6Cdsp/32/

It's a UL inside a div.  That ul is data-bound to an array using knockout "foreach" binding.  As it grows, I need to be able to scroll horizontally within the container.

I can get a horizontal scroll-bar on the div if I set a static width on the UL.

If the only solution is to set a static width on the UL and then increase that using JQuery or something as new items get added to the array, then you can just say so and I'll get it to work that way, I'm just really hoping there's a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need of a wrapper for ul than can itself show a scroll bar

no need really to set an height

white-space is your friend :)

here reduced css :

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Cdsp/33/

Comment: white-space:nowrap;  -- that was the silver bullet that I was missing.  Thank you